# pipreqs generte requirement.txt on Mac due to SSL error

Tags: python, pip, ssl-certificate, requirements.txt

I am trying to generate `requirement.txt` file for the python code. I also got the error while running the `pip3 install`, so I was able to use the below command to install packages with the help of additional options:

```
pip3 install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org <package-name>
```

while running the `pipreqs .` inside the code directory I am getting below error:

```
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

when I tried to run the below command:

```
pipreqs --trusted-host=pypi.org --trusted-host=pypi.python.org --trusted-host=files.pythonhosted.org .
```

I am getting syntax error:

```
Usage:
   pipreqs [options] [<path>]
```

Regards,

Comment: Don't post pictures, post code, besides, that picture seems cut off.